# Неполное предложение и тире

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

Нужно ли ставить тире в следующем предложении?

> Два часа или чуть меньше (-) чтение книг и журналов.

Или такое предложение вообще недопустимо на письме, и нужно написать вот так:

> Чтение книг и журналов в течение двух часов или чуть меньше.

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть это предложение в контексте.

Comment: Да, важно знать, о чём это: о распределении известного количества времени, которое нужно каким-то образом использовать, или о планировании нужных дел. Во втором случае нужен другой порядок слов (количество времени в конце).

Comment: _Во втором случае нужен другой порядок слов (количество времени в конце)._ Я думаю, что это — личное дело каждого (кто как привык): 1,5 — дети; 3 — компьютер; 2,5 — тренировка; ~2 — газеты...

Answer (score 2):

Хотелось бы увидеть это предложение в контексте. Если вопрос о том, в каком контексте такая фраза может появиться, то вот вам пример:

**Три часа отнял просмотр телепрограмм, два часа или чуть меньше — чтение книг и журналов, поэтому домашнее задание я сделать не успел.**

Answer (score 2):

**Два часа или чуть меньше — чтение книг и журналов.**

Предложение можно считать **эллиптическим**,  такие предложения строятся по одной из схем: подлежащее — дополнение, подлежащее — обстоятельство (или в обратном порядке).

В приведенном предложении первая часть —  это **обстоятельство времени** (как долго?), а вторая часть — **подлежащее** (что?). Сказуемое в эллиптических предложениях отсутствует и определяется по смыслу (обычно подходят несколько глаголов).

**Для сравнения:** в неполных предложениях  сказуемое восстанавливается из контекста.

Сравнить (двусоставное предложение со сказуемым): **Два часа или чуть меньше** продолжается/длится **чтение книг и журналов.**

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что тире ставить нужно. Здесь отсутствует сказуемое, которое подразумевается, предполагается, "додумывается":
Два часа или чуть меньше [заняло] чтение газет и журналов.

Такая "конфигурация" обычно используется при короткой записи распорядка дня или для анализа потраченного за день времени. Абстрактно:
полтора часа — прогулка с детьми;
три часа — работа за компьютером;
два с половиной — тренировка, бассейн, магазин;
два часа или чуть меньше — чтение газет и журналов...

[Тире в неполном предложении](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=107)